# VBA match and copy cell value between sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets, One labeled "Assignments" and another "Backup". What I am trying to achieve is to copy the information on "Assignments" to "Backup" to allow for new data to be entered.

However, once copied to "Backup" and new information is supplied to "Assignments" I am looking to loop through each item in column A on "Backup" and copy the adjacent cell (Column B) to the corresponding cell value found on "Assignments".

So far this is the code that I have but am not returning any viable results:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Match()
Dim RNG As Range
Dim RI As Range
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim f As Range
Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Assignments")
Set RNG = Sheets("Assignments Backup").Range("A2:A400")
For Each RI In RNG

With WS
    'RI.Select

    Set f = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Find(What:=Cells(Target.Row, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole) '<--| try finding "Emp #" from Assignments sheet changed cell row column B in referenced sheet ("i.e. "Checklist") column "A" cells not blank cells

        If f Is Nothing Then '<--| if "Emp #" match not found



            'MsgBox "I couldn't find " & Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value & " in worksheet 'Checklist'"
        Else ' <-- if "Emp #" match found
            .Range("F:F").Rows(f.Row).Value = Range("F:F").Rows(Target.Row).Value '<--| paste "Assigmnents" sheet changed cell row columns "AA:AF" content in corresponiding columns of referenced sheet ("i.e. "Checklist") row where "Emp #" match was found
        End If

        End With
        Next


End Sub
```

I apologize for the delay, I have uploaded an example file to my google drive. [https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0jgh8FwPVvkWk40TEczYVFjX0k][1]

As you will notice column B contains different data between both sheets. However, as mentioned, I would like the information from column B in backup to replace what is in column B on assignments according to the data in Column A in each. I have also included the code below.

**EDIT**
I updated the code above as I realized that I had not posted the correct code that I was originally attempting to work with.

Comment: Can you post example data(spreadsheet image) before and after?

Comment: `For Each RI In RNG` then you use `Target.Row`... Your variable names are confused/confusing. Please use `Option Explicit` and verify that your variables are declared correctly before asking for any further help.

Comment: I did try to utilize 'Option Explicit' but it did not correct the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My dear friend, your "code" is a mess - and that is a very polite way of putting it. I spent half an hour just to clean it up. But that is only to make the problems visible.

```
Sub MatchEntries()

    Dim WsA As Worksheet                        ' Worksheet "Assignments"
    Dim WsB As Worksheet                        ' Worksheet "Assignments Backup"
    Dim WsC As Worksheet                        ' Worksheet "Checklist"
    Dim Cell As Range                           ' Cells in RngA
    Dim Fnd As Range                            ' Find match
    Dim R As Long, C As Long                    ' row and column

    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set WsA = .Worksheets("Assignments")
        Set WsB = .Worksheets("Assignments Backup")
        Set WsC = .Worksheets("Checklist")
    End With

    For Each Cell In WsB.Range("A2:A400")
        Set Fnd = WsC.Columns(1).Find(What:=Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                  ' <--| try finding "Emp #" from Assignments sheet changed cell row column B
                  ' in referenced sheet ("i.e. "Checklist") column "A" cells not blank cells

        If Fnd Is Nothing Then '<--| if "Emp #" match not found
            MsgBox "I couldn't find " & Cell.Value & " in worksheet 'Checklist'"

        Else ' <-- if "Emp #" match found
            R = Fnd.Row
            For C = 27 To 32                ' columns AA to AF
                WsA.Cells(R, C).Value = WsC.Cells(R, C).Value
            Next C
'            .Range("Fnd:Fnd").Rows(Fnd.Row).Value = Range("Fnd:Fnd").Rows(Target.Row).Value
            ' <--| paste "Assigmnents" sheet changed cell row columns "AA:AF" content
            ' in corresponiding columns of referenced sheet ("i.e. "Checklist") row
            ' where "Emp #" match was found
        End If

    Next Cell
End Sub
```

To start with, don't call your sub "Match". `Match` is a worksheetfunction, and there is no telling what Excel will do when it meets "your" choice of name.

Second, you seem to have 3 sheets. So, I declared 3 sheets. From your post it isn't possible to tell if that assumption is correct or not, but you can see the logic, I believe. Also, once you have so many variables you will need to be a little imaginative with the names. You can't call all your 8 sons John1, John2, John3, etc. By the same token I named one of your ranges `Cell` and another `Fnd`. You will be able to tell the difference between them by their names.

Now you can see that you are looking through all the cells in column A of the Backup sheet (`WsB`). That doesn't look like a very good idea because there are likely to be a lot of blank cells. Matches will be found for them. I took the liberty to presume that you are looking in the Checklist sheet. If that is wrong, it is now easy to change the sheet or the column.

If a match is found you want to do something. I couldn't make out what it is you want to do, but I wrote code there which should be easy for you to understand and modify so that it does what you actually want.